# Windows display date format incorrect

Tags: windows-10

In `Control Panel\Clock and Region\Region`, the format is correctly set to "English (United Kingdom)" and the example for a short date shows `23/11/2020`. The date is correctly displayed on the Taskbar, list of installed applications, Task Scheduler and so on.

[image: Control Panel > Region]

But other parts of Windows show an incorrect date format, such as `Control Panel\System and Security\Security and Maintenance\Automatic Maintenance\Last run date`. This looks like a "English (United States)" date format.

[image: Control Panel > Maintenance]

Is this a bug in Windows and can this be corrected?

Comment: Mine is showing 23/11 on Last Run... so it looks like a specific locale setting. Run `Get-WinSystemLocale`, `Get-Culture`, `Get-WinUserLanguageList` & `Get-WinHomeLocation` in Powershell. What comes back? It should all be `en-GB` or English (United Kingdom).

Comment: Suspect that while the system locale is properly set the user’s locale isn’t

Comment: @spikey_richie: `Get-WinSystemLocale` return "English (United States)". All the others return "United Kingdom".

Comment: Have gone into `Control Panel\Clock and Region\Region\Administrative\Language for non-Unicode programs` and changed the system locale from "English (United States)" to "English (United Kingdom)". Rebooted and `Get-WinSystemLocale` now returns "en-GB", but the original section mentioned in the question (`Maintenance`) still shows "11/23/2020". Possibly this is a hard-coded string which will be updated when the task next runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment in the question.

Run the below Powershell to set your system locale to English (UK)

`Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale en-GB`

An alternative approach (made by the OP) is to set the system locale appropriately in `Region\Administrative\Language for non-Unicode programs\Change system locale`

Two caveats;

1. You might need to reboot for the settings to stick.
2. The timestamp on the previous maintenance job won't update. It will however show correctly after the next maintenance job has finished.